# Can I do hasMany relationships in Ember with Model-specific data for each?

Tags: ember.js

Okay, so, without giving way too much detail, I'm trying to build an RPG character sheet as my first project with ember.js (though, I've already done the TodoMVC tutorial, as well as Tom Dale's video guide, and the Peepcode video. It is, however, likely that I've already lost/forgotten bits and pieces, so forgive me if this question is covered there).

Basically, just tracking character stats and whatnot. Most of the stats are pretty straightforward, as they're just strings/numbers. What's tripping me up a bit is when I get to things like character inventory, skills, etc.

For example, in trying to set up my data model, I've got this for the simple attributes:

```
App.Character = DS.Model.extend({
  species: DS.attr('string'),
  career: DS.attr('string'),
  gender: DS.attr('string'),
  age: DS.attr('number'), 
  height: DS.attr('number'),
  hair: DS.attr('string'),
  notableFeatures: DS.attr('string'),
  (etc., etc.)
});
```

Now, for other attributes, like, say, an astrogation skill, I've got both the skill name and the rank the character has in that skill.

One option would be to just get kind of lazy and set up each skill as follows:

```
  skillAstrogation: DS.attr('number')
```

I don't feel like that's quite in the "spirit" of things, though, and it would make it harder for me to add/remove skills later on if necessary. Also, I'd like, at some point, for the user to be able to add their own skills.

So, after asking on reddit, and doing some more research, it looks like I should be using a many-to-many relationship. That is, set up a separate model for "skills", and give each a name, rank, etc. (there's another field or two I'll want, as well).

Something like this:

```
App.Character = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  skills: DS.hasMany("App.Skill")
});

App.Skill = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  rank: DS.attr('number'),
  characters: DS.hasMany("App.Character")
});
```

What I'm not entirely clear on, though, is how I then set the rank for each character per-skill, if that makes sense.

Maybe "rank" shouldn't be in App.Skill? Should it be in the Character model, instead?

I hope I'm being clear, here. :)

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand correctly what you want is not actually many to many but many to one. Each skill rank only corresponds with one Character right? Now you might feel that this is adding a lot of duplicate content since the title would be copied each time, in this case you would actually like 3 models.

Something like this:

```
App.Character = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  skills: DS.hasMany("App.Linkage")
});

App.Linkage = DS.Model.extend({
    rank: DS.attr('number'),
    character: DS.belongsTo("App.Character")
    skill: DS.belongsTo("App.Skill")
});

App.Skill = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
});
```

To now retrieve the data you could do the following:

route:

```
model: function () {
    return App.Character.find();
}
```

template:

```
 <ul>
        {{#each character in controller}}
            <li>{{character.name}} -
                {{#each item in character.skills }}
                    {{item.skill.skill}}: {{item.rank}},
                {{/each}}
            </li>
         {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Comment: Each character has their own rank in a skill, but the list of skills itself is shared between every character. I'm on my phone ATM, but I'll look a bit deeper at your solution when I get home tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Still not on a computer, but I was excited to check this out again. So, it looks like you're suggesting that I have one model for characters, one model for skills, then one model to track each character's rank in each skill? So, the "linkage" model is going to have <skills> * <characters> records in it? Doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: Okay, so I set up the models you suggested. I'm fairly certain I get how those will be set up. Mostly. What I'm not terribly clear on is how to automatically populate a model's (say, one of my characters) skill attribute. That is, when I was just doing a single hasMany relationship, I could just, in the fixture data, specify an array containing the IDs of every skill. With the linkage, though, am I still going to have to have the server store and process all of that, or can I have Ember look for something like "All records with a character property of '2'"? If so, how? (thanks btw!)

Comment: Yes Ember could get all your records for you, I have updated the answer to reflect that.